# C++/CLI Printing contents of CString to console

Tags: c++-cli, cstring

C++ newbie here with a quick question.  How do I print the contents of CString to the Console?

Doing this

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{               
    CString cs1 = _T("Hy");
    CString cs2 = _T(" u");
    CString cs3 = cs1 + cs2;

    Console::WriteLine(cs3);    
    printf("%s", cs3);  
    return 0;
}
```

outputs "True" and "H" on the console.  TIA.

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place? I.e., why use `CString` over `System::String^` in C++/CLI?

Comment: Just a test sample to learn some C++ string basics.  Legacy app is using Cstring.

Comment: If you're just learning the basics, then it's worth noting that `CString` is *MFC's* string class; the C++ standard library's string class is [`std::string`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/basic_string/start).

Comment: Oh, and the language you're using is **not** C++, it's C++/CLI. If you actually intend to be using/learning C++, then you're off on the wrong foot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're compiling with Unicode turned on, but `printf` is an ANSI function, so it prints only the first character of the string. Use `_tprintf` to match your `_T` strings:

```
_tprintf(_T("%s"), cs3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Console::WriteLine(gcnew System::String(cs3));
```

Comment: I changed to a Win32 console app instead so I no longer have access to Console.  Thank anyway.

Comment: @KlausNji That's nice for you, but read the question if you will. Your `main` is `int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)` and that is categorically a managed process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your CString before printing

```
printf("%s ", (LPCTSTR)cs3);
```

This should work

Comment: I think this is technically correct, but ISTR CString is actually arranged so that you can get away with misbehaving here.

Comment: This displays first character in string.